# T-SQL - Convert datetime to unseparated ISO value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to convert the following `DATETIME` into ISO format:

```
-- Today's Date
2018-04-16 2:04PM
```

I plan on parsing this into a `char` value as `NVARCHAR` so that I can concatenate it as part of a string.

Desired result should be:

```
-- Date and time unseparated
20180416140422
```

After some research I discovered [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that

```
CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 112)
```

using the 112 format code should get me the format I want but somehow I get the following sample output:

```
--Formatted using 112 format
Apr 16 2018 2:04PM
```

Why is this? I simply want to format the `DATETIME` object unseparated.

Also how would I do this with or without the time tagged onto the end?

Using SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: Your code would return that if you were doing something like converting that to varchar. But just the query posted would not return that format.

Comment: Thanks Sean, It appears to have been a simple change of datatype that resolved my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be :

```
select CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 112)
```

**Output**

```
20180416
```

If you want date & time both, then can try using this :

```
select CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 112) + replace(CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 108), ':', '')
```

**Output**

```
20180416193327
```

Comment: Thank you, you are totally correct as switching the converted data type from datetime to varchar has solved the problem. One more question though. 112 works great for dates but how would I tag on the time at the end also?

Comment: Good answer +1 but your output will not be correct tomorrow with that in your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
--20180416152520
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 121), '-', ''), ':', ''), ' ', '') AS DesiredFormat
```

**Output:**

```
20180416152520
```

Comment: why use 121 and cut out stuff, when you just can use 112 and it will already be in the correct format ? This is so much extra work to achieve the same result

Comment: Perhaps because 112 cuts a time part and @MasterYoda needs it also

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I had hoped that there might be an existing format for keeping the time part but this works just as well :)

Comment: I would recommend still to consider a format: 126, since this one a locale independent standard of SQL Server

Comment: or upgrade to SQL Server 2012 or higher, then you can use the `format`function

Comment: @GuidoG I wish I could, maybe in a few years when we convince some of our customers to upgrade :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 112) AS ISODate
  , CONVERT(varchar(50), GETDATE(), 126) AS ISOWithTime_WorksWithAnyLanguageSetting;
```

I believe the names of the columns are self-explanatory.

Output example:

```
ISODate     | ISOWithTime_WorksWithAnyLanguageSetting
------------------------------------------------------
20180416    | 2018-04-16T15:26:50.607
```

For information on more formats of the `CONVERT` function with examples check [this source](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/).

Answer (score 0):

These all seem a bit overly cumbersome when all you need is `format()`:

```
select format(getdate(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') as ISODateTime;
```